# Какой компилятор С++ выбрать для Виндовс и Линукс?

Tags: windows, компилятор, c++, linux

Здравствуйте, мастера С++. Мне хотелось бы писать защиту (криптография, сетевая защита и т.д.) в глобальной и локальной сетях. Было бы неплохо выбрать один компилятор для написания прог в виндовс и линукс. Какой компилятор С++ посоветуете для виндовс и линукс? Конечно, учитывая количество мануалов по этому компилятору. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Всем спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 1):

Если нужен общий компилятор для линя и винды, тогда gcc или Intel C++

**P.S.** Я вот только не понимаю желания использовать для двух платформ один и тот же компилятор. Если нужно писать переносимый код, надо использовать стандартные функции и классы и кроссплатформенные библиотеки (типа Qt). А каким компилятором их собирать под конкретную платформу - дело десятое.

К тому же поставленные Вами задачи наверняка потребуют системного программирования, тех же сокетов, а здесь без специфичных для каждой ОС API не обойтись.

Comment: Ну ещё есть американское ругательство standard compliance

Comment: Да я переносить может и буду в редких случаях.Почем справшивал про один компилятор так потому что не знаю синтаксис в С++ везде на 100 процентов одинаковый или нет.А так мне все равно какой компилятор использовать.Вот например асм.Я буду учить Masm под винду и Nasm под линукс.У них отличие в ситнаксисе есть.

Comment: Если нужен асм под линь, учи как NASM, так и GAS с его AT&T синтаксисом. Кстати, под винду тоже есть NASM

Comment: Я вообще думал использовать Nasm под две системы но где то прочитал статью в которой автор сказал что Nasm под виндовс будет учить непросто учитывая что статей готовых программ и т.д. мало.Типа Masm рулит.Только собака он багистый.

Answer (score 1):

Возможный вариант - [clang](http://llvm.org/) (C/C++/Objective C). В основном нацелен на Unix-подобные системы (Linux, MacOS, FreeBSD), но работает также и под Windows.

Answer (score 1):

> Конечно, учитывая количество мануалов по этому компилятору.

У всех компиляторов есть информация о том, какие параметры командной строки существуют, как называются и что делают. Больше для использования компилятора ничего не надо. Стандарт C++ везде один.

> Мне хотелось бы писать защиту (криптография, сетевая защита и т.д.) в глобальной и локальной сетях.

Компилятору всё-равно, что ты будешь писать.

Под Linux я знаю только о GCC (и из предыдущего ответа узнал про Intel C++). Просто устанавливаешь IDE и компилятор у тебя уже есть. Не надо думать о том, какой компилятор выбрать и как им пользоваться.

А может быть ты имел в виду не компилятор, а IDE? А то новички часто путают эти понятия.
 При программировании под Windows большинство программистов используют Visual Studio. Если тебе нужна общая среда разработки и под Windows и под Linux, то выбери какой-нибудь NetBeans или Eclipse.

Comment: Intel C++ Compiler - замечательный оптимизирующий компилятор.

Comment: Я про Intel C++ был в сомнениях т.к. книг не много.Вот уже не раз слышал и читал что С++ один т.к. язык стандартизован.Насколько мне известно различие есть в библиотеках.А все функции и синтаксис имеют стопроцентное сходство т.е. я могу взять любой синтаксис С++ и использовать на любом компиляторе С++ без изменения?Если да то смогу сам выбрать.

Comment: Стандарт - это некий минимум, которому должны удовлетворять компиляторы, поддерживающие этот стандарт. Есть несколько стандартов С++. Последний - С++11 - был принят буквально на днях. Последний "стабильный" стандарт был принят в 98 году. Между ними было несколько промежуточных предварительных стандартов. Практически все современные компиляторы поддерживают С++98. С++11 полностью не поддерживает еще никто.

Comment: Однако для полноценного программирования использования только стандартных вещей мало. Он не определяет ни графики, ни низкоуровневых вещей и т.д. Для этого нужно применение либо специальных библиотек, либо использование API системы. Кроме того, почти каждый компилятор предлагает свои примочки, для оптимизации, лучшего контроля над программой и т.д. 

По вопросу заключаю, что Вы еще новичек. Если так, то учите обычный C++98 и не парьте обо всем остальном. Придет в свое время.

Comment: Ну я пока не силен в программировании.Освоил Delphi и имею небольшой опыт.Мне С++ больше по специальности подойдет.О С++98 ваще не слышал.Я наверно сразу предпочту Intel C++ или другой...Пока подумаю:)

Comment: Intel C++ - это не стандарт, а компилятор. Причем использовать его для обычных программ я бы не стал. Он очень хорош для параллельных вычислений, научных работ и т.д. Но работать с ним не очень удобно. Особенно создавать графический интерфейс под вин.

Если под вин - Dev-C++ или Visaul Studio и не парься.